# SQL conditional insert into

Tags: sql, derby

Is it possible to insert into a table based on a count condition (using just 1 statement)? 
I want to do something like this:

```
insert into [table] (...) values (...) if select count(*) from [table] < 5
```

(insert into the table only if it has less than 5 entries)

Comment: What RDBS are you using?

Comment: Square brackets around identifiers suggests sql-server, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this:

```
insert into [table] (#FIELDS#)
select (#VALUES#) from [table]
where (select count(*) from [table]) < 5
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
insert into [table] (...) values Select (...) from [table] Where count(*) < 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, above solutions does not include *group by* command. It leads to error. I suppose that you want to insert all rows which has count less than 5, but grouped by some column. Please correct me if I am wrong.

For example: we have table "table" with rows "ID" and "name", and we want to select and insert only those rows which name is not repeating more than 5 times in a table.

select * from table where name in ( select name from table group by name having count(*)<5 )

I would also consider using select into command. Good luck :)

**Well, I think that I have just understood your problem, and I think that my answer is not about it. Anyway, I hope that my answer will be helpful for you or someone else.**

Comment: no. i just want to make sure that the table has max. 5 entries, no matter some fields repeat or not. i don't want validations, i don't want group by. i just want to allow max 5 entries in the table